# What is difference between Jquery Function Template and Method Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I am not clear between Jquery Function Template and Method Template and how to use them. The following snippet of Function Template and Method Template but what is basic differences between them.

**Function Template:-**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myFirstPlugin = function(settings){

    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Method Template:-**

```
(function($){
$.myPlugin = function(settings){

  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Function Template

Defines method for selector , e.g.; `$("html").myFirstPlugin()` where `this` : `"html"` , selector

> Method Template

Defines function as property of jQuery object , e.g.; `$.myPlugin()` where `this` : `jQuery` , unless set to a different context